# how to import the database to mysql under linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

The sql file named:`bag.sql` in `/var/www/html/web`(/var/www/html/web/bag.sql)

the current directory is `[localhost web]`i used `mysql -uusername -p databasename > bag.sql`

then let me input the password. i wait for long time, it doesn't show ok. why? how to import the database to mysql under centos.

Comment: The command you tried wrote the database out _into_ `bag.sql`, instead of reading from it. How big is `bag.sql`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you have already created database then use below steps to import data from .sql file

tell which database to use:

```
 use databasename;
```

Now give the source file path

```
 source /var/www/html/web/bag.sql;
```

Comment: mysql> use handbag;
Database changed
mysql> source /var/www/html/web/bag.sql;
mysql>

Answer (score 4):

You need `mysql -uusername -p databasename < bag.sql`.

```
<     Means "get the program's input from this file"
>     Means "write the program's output to this file"
```

Comment: when i change to < it still can't import the data into databasename

Comment: You have to have a database called `databasename` already to import to. If you do `mysql --verbose -u username -p databasename < bag.sql` it will show you your queries as they run.

Comment: when i enter the password it turn to [root@localhost web]# why?

Comment: Because either there were no errors or your `bag.sql` is empty. In general well-made Unix command line tools produce no more output than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

1. Connect to mysql database server

   $ mysql -uusername -ppassword
2. Check database exists are not

   $ show databases;
3. If not create the same

   mysql>create database mydb;

   note: mydb is database name(Give your own).
4. Check again for the database follow step 2.
5. exit
6. Import data to mydb(your own) database

   $ mysql -uusername -ppassword mydb < bag.sql

   note: your bag.sql is in the current directory from where you are executing the above       command
7. Check for imported data.

YES FOR LONG WAIT YOU NEED TO CHECK YOUR BAG.SQL FILE SIZE.

Symbol '$' is shell prompt

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer up another alternative using `pv`

`pv /path/to/file.sql | mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -D DATABASE_NAME`

This will show you a progress indicator for the import.  If you have never used `pv` it is a piper viewer tool in linux.

Answer (score 0):

you're using the wrong redirection operator. `>` is used for sending the output *to* a file, not taking input *from* a file. Use `<`.

Answer (score 0):

mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql

[source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/import-mysql-dumpfile-sql-datafile-into-my-database/)